# MethodInfo to Action in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a static List like this:

```
class Program
{
    public static List<Action> List { get; set; } = new List<Action>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.Work();
        var type = test.GetType();
        var method = type.GetMethod("Action1",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        //Console.WriteLine(List.Any(p => p == new Action(method.)));
    }
}
public class Test
{
    public void Work()
    {
        Program.List.Add(new Action(Action1));
    }
    private void Action1()
    {

    }
}
```

How can I judge the Program.List contains Action1 by Reflection?

If the Action1 method is public, I can do like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(List.Any(p => p == new Action(test.Action1)));
```

And it will print "True";

Comment: That's not possible.  You have not finished your code and actually add anything to the list.  Once you do, you'll realize that it contains delegates whose Method will call method.Invoke().  That this Invoke() calls Action1 is not something you can discover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(List.Any(p => p.Method.MethodHandle.Value == method.MethodHandle.Value));
```

Comment: It's Work, but can you translate "Action", Maybe it just has Action interface exposed?

Comment: Maybe use List<MethodInfo>

Comment: I think that Action will be better, because the methods may have parameters and List<Action> stores the methods without parameters.

Comment: Sorry, 
I think that MethodInfo will be better, because the methods may have parameters and List<Action> stores the methods without parameters.